# ionic 2: ionic run android shows error

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

i have error when i run "ionic run android" or "ionic build android" in my ionic 2 app
this is the error i get. i just tryinh to see my app in the emulator of android.
i tried to make new ionic 2 project but it's the same problem.

```
Running 'build:before' npm script before build
> ionic-hello-world@ build C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\tasklist
> ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js
[20:16:33]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.30
[20:16:33]  build prod started ...
[20:16:33]  clean started ...
[20:16:33]  clean finished in 24 ms
[20:16:33]  copy started ...
[20:16:33]  ngc started ...
[20:16:33]  lint started ...
[20:16:33]  copy finished in 182 ms
[20:16:34]  lint finished in 770 ms
[20:16:52]  ngc finished in 18.71 s
[20:16:52]  bundle prod started ...
[20:16:52]  bundle prod failed:  Could not resolve entry (/app/main.prod.ts)

[20:16:52]  Error: Could not resolve entry (/app/main.prod.ts)
    at C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\tasklist\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:8635:28
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Error running ionic app script "build": Error: Could not resolve entry (/app/main.prod.ts)



npm
 ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393

npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!
     ionic-app-scripts build --rollup ./config/rollup.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.



npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\tasklist\npm-debug.log

Caught exception:
 undefined

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues


C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\tasklist>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been a common issue lately with ionic and A2 and resolving `main.prod.*`Try updating you app scripts for the project.

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

Your error message should change after that with what is actually causing your build to crash. If the error message changes please update your question with the new message.

Checkout this out as well for more information on this issue: [Ionic forum](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8312)

Comment: Ok are you running npm 3.x?

Comment: Yeah you are, if this is just an example you are running try completely removing the project and running a new one. There could be something wrong in node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

Close all ionic folders and serve or lab. And try again, `ionic cordova build android`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a path setup problem in your system.

1st check npm version using CMD: npm -v

If it shows version number then use below code, otherwise 1st setup your npm path, you can use gitbash cmd, nodejs cmd

> Try to use

```
ionic cordova run android
```

> or

```
ionic cordova platform remove android

ionic cordova run android
```

> If you have MAC system must use sudo like

```
sudo ionic cordova run android
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### First of all, Check the version of Android in package.json file.

### Now remove platform with this command (ionic cordova platform rm android)

After that addd the platform with this command (ionic cordova platform add

### android@6.4.0). Where 7.0.0 is not stable version so use 6.4.0

Now, run this command (ionic cordova run android) or in mac (sudo ionic cordova run android)

Answer (score 0):

> Try out below command

```
$ cordova clean android
$ cordova build android
$ ionic cordova build android
```